# How is ReadLock any good in ReaderWriterLockSlim?

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

I am learning more about threading in C#. I just don't understand why would I care about "entering" or "exiting" a ReadLock when it actually doesn't do any locking?

Comment: I am confused by the question. Entering a read lock either takes the lock or blocks until it can be taken; can you say why you believe that entering a read lock does not either take the lock or block?

Comment: Without understanding more about the source of your confusion it is going to be hard to rid you of whatever false belief it is that you have.

Comment: I thought there will never be any "blocking". But Amy's answer has explained it.

Comment: If the read lock is unavailable -- because the write lock is taken -- then the readers block until the read lock is available. If the read lock is taken then that blocks writers from obtaining the write lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't do any locking?  It gets a *read lock*.

What happens if something currently has a write lock?  You can't read, you need to wait.  Everyone who wants to read needs to wait until the write lock is released.

But many objects can have concurrent read locks, since reading doesn't mutate the object and can't cause a race condition.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock for more information.

Comment: This applies in both directions: While you have a read lock, someone else who wants a write lock has to wait.